# Cannot insert character 'N' to PostgreSQL in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have data object as below:

```
const sStatus = "N";
const oMemberCard = {
  code: memberCardCode,
  member: memberCode,
  status: sStatus,
  status_datetime: moment().format(),
};
```

I use Sequelize to insert but have error:

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "mb_member_card"
> ("member","code","status","status_datetime") VALUES
> ('A001132203','0315099359','NaN','2020-10-18 00:33:32.000 +07:00');
> [ERROR] SequelizeDatabaseError: value too long for type character(1)

I tried use **escape("N")** but not success.
Anybody can help me! Thanks.

**SOLDED**
I mistake field type in model. Sorry!

Comment: It seems that `status` column is numeric/integer and not char/string

Comment: ANd what type of this column in a Sequelize model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is - your trying to insert *NaN* not *N* on Your status column which is character type with length  limit 1, check the `oMemberCard` variable especially status element  first before passing it to sequalize.